# Should I delete/close this question and re-post?

Tags: discussion

In the following question I ask how to wire a switch/outlet combo. This is the question: [Switch/outlet combo with constant power in outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/234977/switch-outlet-combo-with-constant-power-in-outlet)?

I guess the problem with the question was that it wasn't clear initially, and the answers that I received, even though they were good, don't really answer the question.

The question is much clearer now after editing, but it stopped receiving any attention.

Should I just close it and then re-ask?

Answer (score 3):

Recreating a question to get attention is frowned upon, and often results in the new question getting down voted and closed as a duplicate.

Instead, to get attention to an existing question, the suggested method is to [open a bounty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). If there are existing answers on the question that don't answer the question you've asked, then a comment on their answer to explain how your question is different may help.

That said, it's also a good idea to avoid constantly mutating a question, treating the site as your support service. People answering questions do so to create a public knowledge base and hopefully get some virtual points in the process. Make sure you are asking a clear question that can be useful to future visitors, and when an answer solves that question, accept the answer. If that leads to a new question, then it's a good idea to raise the new question.